# If Statement with Boolean Condition

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, if-statement, boolean

I've got some really simple code in visual studio that, for whatever reason, is not working.  I've narrowed the problem down to my boolean condition in the if statement.  Here is a simplified version:

```
Dim bool As boolean

Protected Sub Button1Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
If bool = true Then
    bool = false
ElseIf bool = false Then
    bool = true
End If
Label1.Text = bool
End Sub
```

This is within a button click event.  If bool is initially set to true, when I click it, it goes to false, but then if I click it again the "bool = false" statement is not executed.

Edit: As asked, the full button click handler has been added to the code above. As asked, this is for an asp.net website.  The point of this code is to, on a button click, change the style of a header element on a button click.  However, this has no effect on the question, as I took that code out temporarily to reduce any potential problems and was left with the code above.

Comment: This code works for me.  There must be something else going on that you aren't showing.  Can you show the entire button click event handler?

Comment: What language is this in?

Comment: @rageandqq -- looks to be VB.NET

Comment: @roryap Added full code.

Comment: @JonW -- Thanks.  I still don't see how it's not working.  It works fine for me.  If you set break points on `bool = false` and `bool = true`, doesn't clicking the button again and again alternately break on each of those?

Comment: @roryap I did that, and for the first click it worked, whether bool was set to false or true it switched to the other one.  But once it switches, the other breakpoint isnt even going off.  I.E. if it's initially set to true, it'll display that, and then I click the button, and it'll switch to false and display as so.  But when I click the button again the code does not execute, and it stays as false.

Comment: You might have something that changes the bool value elsewhere. What do you mean by "does not execute" it doesn't even go in the click function?

Comment: @the_lotus the only other location that bool has in my code is in the Page Load event, and it just is Label1.Text = bool.  Aka just displaying the initial value.  As far as I know the click function doesn't happen at all after the initial click. However, I don't have any code other than what's above to test whether it's getting held up on the click value, or if it is clicking and just not executing the if statement.

Comment: In your code you forgot the `Then` keywords after your condition in the `If` and `ElseIf` statements.

Comment: @GeorgJung Actually, I forgot it in the code up above, I have it in my actual code in visual studio.  I'll throw that in up there to avoid confusion.

Comment: So if you talk about the Page_Load event, are you asking about an ASP.Net Website? Please add more details to your original question.

Comment: @GeorgJung Added in more details, although I'm not sure how they are relevant to the question.

Comment: If this is a webpage, than all your variable will be reset on each postback since the [web is statless](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=vs.85).aspx). If you want to keep the variable, you need to find a way to store it querystring/form/viewstate/session/cache.

Comment: Your event handler might not be called because your aspx frontend code is wrong, but I can not tell more about that without seeing that code. Maybe you forget `runat="server"` or something similar.

Comment: Another option is that you overwrite your boolean value in some init event, which is called on every reload (i.e. a button click). For debugging purposes you could change `Label1.Text = bool` to `Label1.Text &= bool` to see the changes of your variable and to see when your code is run. A better option would be to use breakpoints and visual studio's debugger.

Comment: @the_lotus I'm not sure that's the problem.  I just added a button that does a postback, and it keeps the variable to whatever it last was.

Comment: @GeorgJung I've looked around the frontend, the only difference between this button and the hundreds I've made before is this one is an ImageButton, which I don't think would effect it's operation in the slightest.  Just tried your &=, no affect.  Actually, changing it to &= did have an effect, it shows me that the button click event definitely is happening, as it appends the variable value to the label on every button click.  So for whatever reason, the ElseIf statement is not executing.

Comment: Asp.Net (Web Forms) automatically saves your control's properties, kind of making your requests stateful. I'm not sure if it saves your local variables too but I believe it does not. First of all try using @rageandqq's code instead of your If statements.

Comment: @GeorgJung Already tried it.  Same effect.  Note- I did keep the if function in there for the rest of my code, I just took out the setting bool to whichever and added in bool = not bool at the end.

Comment: if you set a breakpoint on the first line inside the button click event, what happens on button clicks after the first? is the `bool` variable truly keeping it's value?

Answer (score 9):

It seems like all you're doing is toggling the value of the boolean flag.
Assuming it is always either `true` or `false`, you can just invert the value:

```
booleanVar = Not booleanVar
```

Comment: I don't know why you were downvoted. This is a good way to replace the if statement all together.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted should obviously be working, taken by itself. Your problem might be that the value of `bool` is not saved between different web requests. You need to save that value. Try using the `HttpContext`'s `Session` property like this:

```
Dim bool as Boolean
If Session.Item("bool") Is Nothing Then
    Session("bool") = True
End If
bool = DirectCast(Session("bool"), Boolean)
```

For more information see the [MSDN Session State Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581(v=vs.140).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb) and the linked "How to" articles about session information [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.session(v=vs.140).aspx?&cs-lang=vb).

**Edit**:
For making your code more readable and to not clutter your click event handler you can write the following to methods:

```
Private Function GetBoolValue() as Boolean
    If Session.Item("bool") Is Nothing Then
        Session("bool") = True
    End If
    Return DirectCast(Session("bool"), Boolean)
End Function

Private Sub SetBoolValue(value as Boolean)
    Session("bool") = value
End Sub
```

Comment: And this should all go within the same button click event?

Comment: After putting it in the button click event, same problem happens.  Works on the first click, then does nothing on any successive clicks after that.